# can crypto++ use [Private]key object be used simultaneously [in multi threads]

Tags: c++, multithreading, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

supposed we have global `CryptoPP::ECIES<CryptoPP::ECP>::PrivateKey mykey` initialized object 
,and have 10 threads that run `CryptoPP::ECIES<CryptoPP::ECP>::Encryptor myencrypto(mykey)` for making a encryptor object by assigning key from mykey object

the assigner takes mykey as reference

do i need a Mutex to make sure that only one thread uses mykey at a time , or multi threads can assign enryptor from key object simultaneously without any problem (if yes , is that guaranteed)

(please note that threads only assign from the mykey simultaneously  none of them modify it(my code doesn't don't know  if the cryptoPP assigner does ))

Comment: I'm not familiar with crypto++, but traditionally if a class is well designed then an instance should be implicitly shareable across threads provided non of the threads try to change  the instance. In other words, if you pass a `const T &` between threads then that `T` should be safely accessible concurrently. I believe this is required for a type to be compatible with standard containers. Developers are free to break this requirement though and you might never notice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i checked CryptoPP assigner class , it takes the key as const reference [ PK_FinalTemplate(const CryptoMaterial &key)  ] , so it should be safe as you mentioned , i'll wait for an answer from some one familiar with Crypto++ to close the question ,thanks

Comment: I have no reason to think that there would be any problem, since a key is just data.

Comment: @MikeRobinson that's the exact question , is cryptoPP privatekey object normal data as any other byte array key or it does some calculations when a encryptor is being assigned with it , since it has many functions in it's class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After not receiving an answer i picked the mutex locks from my code and tested a few time
when PrivateKey  object was used simultaneously by multi thread  for initializing mutli encryptors

i was getting a assert at intger.cpp (cryptoPP lib source file) at line 2910

```
CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(bcLen <= N);
```

tested about 10 times ,and go the same assert , putted the mutex locks again and the assert was gone (in release mood i was getting 0xc000005 (access denied) at ntdll.dll because HeapFree() fucntion were being called with wrong argument